# Can't able to connect redshift from my springboot application using JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, amazon-redshift

i am working on Springboot application and need to store data into redshift using the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

But i can't able to acheive the connection between the redshift and my springboot application.

**Here is my dependency from pom.xml:**

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
            <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.43.1067</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

**My Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:redshift://hostaddress
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
```

**My Java Model class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "public", name = "SampleModel")
public class SampleModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    private int year;

    private int month;

    private BigDecimal price;

    private BigDecimal total;
}
```

**Exception StackTrace:**

```
2021-01-04 19:00:53.378  INFO 5152 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.DomainInfo        : Building interface class map for 32 classes
2021-01-04 19:00:53.390  INFO 5152 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.DomainInfo        : Post-processing complete
2021-01-04 19:00:55.768  INFO 5152 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. ([Amazon][JDBC](10220) Driver does not support this optional feature.)
2021-01-04 19:00:55.797  INFO 5152 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-01-04 19:00:57.056  INFO 5152 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect
2021-01-04 19:00:57.450 ERROR 5152 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.j.e.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl   : Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database

java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "information_schema.sequences" does not exist;
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.messages.inbound.ErrorResponse.toErrorException(Unknown Source) ~[redshift-jdbc42-1.2.43.1067.jar:na]
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleErrorResponse(Unknown Source) ~[redshift-jdbc42-1.2.43.1067.jar:na]
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleMessage(Unknown Source) ~[redshift-jdbc42-1.2.43.1067.jar:na]
    at com.amazon.jdbc.communications.InboundMessagesPipeline.getNextMessageOfClass(Unknown Source) ~[redshift-jdbc42-1.2.43.1067.jar:na]
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.doMoveToNextClass(Unknown Source) ~[redshift-jdbc42-1.2.43.1067.jar:na]
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.moveThroughMetadata(Unknown Source) ~[redshift-jdbc42-1.2.43.1067.jar:na]
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.getNoData(Unknown Source) ~[redshift-jdbc42-1.2.43.1067.jar:na]
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.directExecuteExtraMetadataWithMessage(Unknown Source) ~[redshift-jdbc42-1.2.43.1067.jar:na]
    at com.amazon.redshift.dataengine.PGQueryExecutor$CallableExecuteTask.call(Unknown Source) ~[redshift-jdbc42-1.2.43.1067.jar:na]
    at com.amazon.redshift.dataengine.PGQueryExecutor$CallableExecuteTask.call(Unknown Source) ~[redshift-jdbc42-1.2.43.1067.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "information_schema.sequences" does not exist;
    ... 13 common frames omitted

2021-01-04 19:00:57.588  INFO 5152 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-01-04 19:00:57.594  INFO 5152 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Did anyone faced this issue or know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Checkout this example - https://github.com/tmheo/spring-data-jpa-redshift-sample

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your connection - you connected successfully. But your application is trying to read from `information_schema.sequences` table, which does not exist in Redshift.

It looks like you have JPA objects with identifiers bound to sequences and you're using PostgreSQL dialect. Your app will try to initialize the objects by reading/creating sequences, but Redshift **does not support sequences**.

I am not sure what you're trying to achieve, but I don't think it's a good idea to have an ORM mapping over Redshift DB (probably that's why there's no Hibernate dialect for Redshift).